# Returning html code

Tags: html, c, http, tcp, tcpclient

I'm using the TCPClient code from [this site](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/client.c) in order to make a basic browsing application in C. When I type `GET /index.html` as the message, it returns this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2013 08:28:44 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=38fb52774c793250:FF=0:TM=1388478524:LM=1388478524:S=8ETV1rNvlBXFrGms; expires=Thu, 31-De
```

How can I edit the code in order to return the html code on the page in addition to the HTTP Session info above?

Comment: You need to understand the protocol. HTTP has headers followed by body. Headers is what you have posted, while body can be any format (mostly in HTML). Refer: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code uses a buffer of 256 bytes, which is often too small to store both the HTTP header and the actual HTML page. You should either user a larger buffer or read multiple times from the socket.

#### Edit

I think replacing the last few lines of the code (after the last write) by

```
do
{
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s",buffer);
} while (n > 0);

printf("\n");
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry could you just explain two things, 1. What this changes how how it changes the function of the program overall and 2. what the bzero function does.

Comment: 'bzero' sets all the bytes to zero (type 'man bzero' for more info). Instead of reading data into the buffer just once, it keeps reading data until the 'read' function says there's nothing left to read.

Comment: @user3131007: `bzero()` is deprecated, use `memset()` instead.